# Filter Nested Array with Same Item That Contain Higest Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

How can i filter this array base on same 'a', and max 'value' in 'a'

```
   data = [
             {a: 1, value: 12}, {a: 11, value: 39}, {a: 11, value: 150},
             {a: 2, value: 15}, {a: 22, value: 83}, {a: 222, value: 12},
             {a: 3, value: 55}, {a: 33, value: 9}, {a: 33, value: 1}
           ]
```

to become

```
data = [
         {a: 1, value: 12}, {a: 11, value: 150},
         {a: 2, value: 15}, {a: 22, value: 83}, {a: 222, value: 12},
         {a: 3, value: 55}, {a: 33, value: 9}, 
       ]
```

i have planty of nasted object array, i cant filter it, same id with diferent value i just want to show the higest on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the index of the result set in a hash table and check if the actual value is greater, then take the actual object as result.

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, value: 12 }, { a: 11, value: 39 }, { a: 11, value: 150 }, { a: 2, value: 15 }, { a: 22, value: 83 }, { a: 222, value: 12 }, { a: 3, value: 55 }, { a: 33, value: 9 }, { a: 33, value: 1 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];
    
data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!(o.a in hash)) {
        hash[o.a] = result.push(o) - 1;
        return;
    }
    if (result[hash[o.a]].value < o.value) {
        result[hash[o.a]] = o;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```